# Is discord.Client compatible with discord.ext.commands for discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a very juvenile bot, and I want to add an automod feature. However, my bot is written in discord.ext.commands, and to scan all the messages, I would need discord.Client (I think). I'm not sure if they can both be run at the same time, but are they compatible?

Comment: There is a event: on_message, which you can use to handle each message. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need discord.Client. If you are already using discord.ext.commands, you can do it as follows.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Bot is ready")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(name="example"))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    forbidden_word = "word"
    if forbidden_word in message.content:
        await message.delete()

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.kick()
    await ctx.send(f"Member {member} has been kicked")


bot.run("token")
```

on_message is called when a Message is created and sent.
discord.Intents.messages must be enabled or you use intents = discord.Intents.all() to enable all Intents